# Not able to setup delete and backspace compatibility in terminal

Tags: 11.04, command-line

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I use the terminal a lot. So, I need to setup the terminal's compatibility to exactly as the Delete and Backspace keys should work. Please tell me what settings should be done.

Comment: They should work by default - what is it you want them to do? If there's a problem then maybe your keyboard isn't set to the correct keymap...

Answer (score 1):

If you log in to another machine through terminal [ssh in reality] then the remote machine takes care of the ex.: "backspace" funtion.

on a SunOS, backspace will not work by default so you have to use bash or:

```
stty erase ^?
```

Comment: I always used `stty erase X` where X was me hitting the backspace key.

Comment: yy, "^?" is outputted when pressing backspace on SunOS's default ksh

Comment: just trying to make it clear for those who haven't done this.  Thanks.